# Travelling from Rome to Fano, Italy by train - Is bus from Ancona a better option?

Tags: public-transport, buses, italy, rome

I am going to be travelling from Rome to Fano, Italy in September and find that the Trenitalia route will take me to Ancona with an hour and a half wait for the next train to Fano.  Since it's only about half an hour from Ancona to Fano...should I consider just getting the train to Ancona and then hopping a bus to Fano from there?  Do the buses run regularly between Ancona and Fano...or should I just wait for the my train connection to be on the safe side?

Comment: I could not find any bus between Ancona and Fano...but there is always [BlaBlaCar](https://www.blablacar.co.uk/search?fn=Ancona&fc=43.6158299%7C13.518915&fcc=&tn=Fano&tc=43.8398164%7C13.0194201&tcc=)...

Comment: Ok thanks.  I guess there are no buses then. I didn't know about BlaBlaCar...very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There might be no buses between Ancona and Fano, however there seem to be buses between Rome and Fano. According to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Rome/Fano) these are operated by [Adriabus](http://www.adriabus.eu) and depart daily from Roma Tiburtina train station. The total travel time is of about 04h30m which looks shorter than your train journey with the included 1h30m waiting time in Ancona.

Should you prefer taking the train to Ancona, [your options for getting to Fano](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Ancona/Fano) seem to be train, taxi, or rideshare ([blablacar](http://www.blablacar.it) or equivalent).